# How does this inequality follow? Fatou's Lemma and DCT

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3046971/785197) answer, and I am not sure how we get
$$
\int g-\int f\leq \int g-\limsup\int f_n.
$$
I see that the integral can distribute over the $-$ on the LHS, but I am not seeing how the $\liminf$ becomes a $\limsup$ on the RHS. Why is it that
$$
\liminf\int(g-f_n)\leq\int g-\limsup\int f_n?
$$
I am sure I am just missing something simple here.

Comment: It easily follows from $|f| \leq g$ and $f_n \to f$ a.e. After this use property of liminf

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/334114/148510. $\liminf(x_n) = - \limsup(-x_n)$